# How to unpack items from a List?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to "unpack" items from a `List` into 4 separate `val`s

```
def myFunc(myList: List[Int]): Unit = {
    val (w,x,y,z) = myList
    // Compile error
}
```

If I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error:(16, 9) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3, T4)
 required: List[Int]
    val (w, x, y, z) = myList
        ^
```

So, it looks like the compiler can't infer that everything coming out of a `List[Int]` is actually still `Int`s. Is there a way to parameterize assignments like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pattern match a list using a 4-tuple extractor. Try this instead:

```
scala> val a :: b :: c :: d :: rest = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
d: Int = 4
rest: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7)

scala> val (a, b, c, d) = (1, 2, 3, 4)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
d: Int = 4
```

Comment: This doesn't work outside of REPL (when one is in the same scope).

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively to Ionut's answer you can also do this:

```
scala> val List(a, b, c, d) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
d: Int = 4
```

Which might be more in-line with what you tried in the beginning

If the list is longer than the required number of elements you can also do this:

```
scala> val List(a, b, c, rest @ _*) = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
rest: Seq[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Alternatively to your answer, you can do `val Seq(a, b, c, d) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)` :-)

Comment: Please note that this might fail at runtime if the list's length is different than 4.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I took care of that minor design flaw